# How to compile a windows app so I can use it on Linux? (like .AppIage)

Tags: arch-linux, windows, compiling, application

I would like to run `NoteMaster` on Linux.

I tried to use `wine` but it didn't work.
[This is the source code.](https://github.com/LiamRiddell/NoteMaster)

The app is written in `JavaScript`, it is an electron app.
Is there a way to compile it so I can run it on Linux? I'm am using Arch Linux.

Comment: [electron-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder) supports Appimage as a target format. electron-builder is a complete solution to package and build a ready for distribution Electron, Proton Native app for macOS, Windows and Linux with “auto update” support out of the box, so give your NoteMaster app a whirl with electron-builder.

Comment: Thanks karel, so it basically lets me to change .exe to .AppImage?

Comment: [electron-webpack-quick-start](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack-quick-start) is a recommended way to create a new Electron application. See [Boilerplates](https://www.electron.build/#boilerplates).

Comment: oh sure, thanks.

Comment: But does it mean i can't if I can't find the package on npm? (The "electron builder" you mentioned in the first comment)

Comment: I already downloaded electron-builder from their GitHub page and cloned it with `git clone` to a directory in my home directory. The command I used is `git clone https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder.git` Then I started with the Quick Setup Guide section in the README.md file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111618/discussion-between-karel-and-qaq-123).